# TestNG "getCurrentXmlTest()).getAllParameters()" API using very old testng-5.4-jdk15.jar TestNG library

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng, testng-dataprovider

For some reason I have to use old TestNG library which doesn't have `"getCurrentXmlTest()).getAllParameters()"` API

How should I get all TestXML parameter using **testng-5.4-jdk15.jar**

For latest TestNG version, this is how we get all params but how can I simulate such a code using testng-5.4-jdk15.jar

```
@DataProvider(name = "DataFile")
public Object[][] testdata(ITestContext context) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = (((ITestContext)context).getCurrentXmlTest())
            .getAllParameters();
    return new Object[][] { { parameters } };
}
```

P.S. :- I can't upgrade jar :(

Comment: Can I ask why you cannot upgrade the jar? At least to 5.11-jdk15

Comment: And why are you using data provider here instead of the parameters feature? http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml

Comment: Change your management ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From TestNG 5.5 sources (because 5.4 sources and binaries are not available on maven central), this following should work:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = (((TestRunner)context).getTest()).getParameters();
```

Comment: can you please help me to get equivalent packages for old jar

`import org.testng.IInvokedMethod`,  `import org.testng.collections.Lists;`

Comment: It looks `IInvokedMethod` didn't exist in 5.5 and you are not supposed to need `Lists`. But for your information both classes are available in 5.11 (the latest 5.x-jdk5 version which, with luck, will be more acceptable for your management).

Comment: Another solution will be to fork TestNG but 5.5 is sooo old than there is no tag in the official SCM (first tag is 5.11)